# Scrape text under br tag under class

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I've been trying to scrape addresses in this page:
https://www.yellowpages.my/listing/results.php?keyword=boutique&where=selangor&screen=2

It is difficult for me to get the address under the br tag:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYMjP.png)

What i've tried

```html
addresses = page_content.select(' .cbp-vm-address')[0]
address = addresses.get_text(' ', strip=True)
address = list(addresses.stripped_strings)
```

which doesn't give me everything under the class

i've also tried:

```html
for br in page_content.findAll('br'):
   item = br.next_siblings
   item = list(item)
   print(item)
```

which gives me results as below (snippet):
`[<br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, <br/>, '\n', <a href="/solutions">DigitalSolutions</a>, '\n', <a href="https://www.yellowpages.my/deal/results.php">Deals</a>, '\n', <a class="sign-up" href="https://www.yellowpages.my/profile/add.php">Sign Up</a>, '\n', <a class="sign-up" href="https://www.yellowpages.my/profile/login.php">Login</a>, '\n']`

How do i get the address? relatively new to scraping here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ohad for the quick response. I just want to slightly improve the answer below:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

raw = requests.get("https://www.yellowpages.my/listing/results.php?keyword=boutique&where=selangor&screen=2")
# raw = raw.replace("</br>", "") # try not to do this
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw.content, "lxml") # instead, change "html.parser" to "lxml"
addresses = [x.text.strip().split("\r\n")[-1].strip() for x in soup.find_all("div", class_="cbp-vm-address")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Interesting. I actually had a problem with this as well but overcame this using replacing all of the `</br>` tags in the raw string before creating the soup object:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

raw = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.my/listing/results.php?keyword=boutique&where=selangor&screen=2').text
raw = raw.replace("</br>", "")
soup = BeautifulSoup(raw, 'html.parser')
addresses = [x.text.strip().split("\r\n")[-1].strip() for x in soup.find_all("div", class_='cbp-vm-address')]
```

Nevertheless, I don't feel like its the best solution as it preprocesses the HTML before loading the soup object, which does not feel like a best practice to me.